# What am I supposed to pass to the following method in Crystal?

Tags: methods, syntax, semantics, crystal-lang

### Background

I'm trying to use [some Cairo bindings for Crystal](https://github.com/TamasSzekeres/cairo-cr), but I'm having some trouble with the syntax and how to call the method below.
It is implemented as such:

```
# Inside Module Cairo, class Surface

# ...

def write_to_png_stream(write_func : LibCairo::WriteFuncT, closure : Void*) : Status
   Status.new(LibCairo.surface_write_to_png_stream(@surface, write_func, closure).value)
end
```

```
# Inside Module LibCairo

# ...

enum StatusT
  SUCCESS = 0

  NO_MEMORY
  INVALID_RESTORE
  # ...
end

# ...

alias WriteFuncT = Void*, UInt8*, UInt32 -> StatusT

# ...

fun surface_write_to_png_stream = cairo_surface_write_to_png_stream(
  surface : PSurfaceT,
  write_func : WriteFuncT,
  closure : Void*
) : StatusT
```

### Question

Specifically, I'm asking how to call the Cairo::Surface#write_to_png_stream method. What do I pass as the `write_func:LibCairo::WriteFuncT`? What do I pass as the `closure: Void*`?

I tried with the following but I haven't managed to get it to work...

```
def my_write_func(a : Void*, b : UInt8*, c : UInt32) : Cairo::C::LibCairo::StatusT
   puts a
   puts b
   puts c

   Cairo::C::LibCairo::StatusT::SUCCESS
end

surface = Cairo::Surface.new Cairo::Format::ARGB32, 400, 300
ctx = Cairo::Context.new surface

ctx.set_source_rgba 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
ctx.rectangle 0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 300.0
ctx.fill

# here, how do I call surface.write_to_png_stream passing my 'my_write_func'?
# a Proc doesn't seem to work.. ( ->my_write_func(Void*, UInt8*, UInt32) )

surface.finish
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working.. Or well, I managed to call it at least.

```
surface.write_to_png_stream ->my_write_func(Void*, UInt8*, UInt32), Pointer(Void).null
```

It turns out it was a Proc afterall as I suspected and that I just needed a null Pointer too.
For future reference, I have an [issue at the repo](https://github.com/TamasSzekeres/cairo-cr/issues/15) talking about the specific usage of this method, but I suppose the syntax/semantics question is answered here on SO.